# Shortest grid walks which

Tags: combinatorics

On a grid, $G = (0,0)$, $E = (3,3)$, $F = (6,9)$, $ H = (9,6)$, $ J = (10,12)$. What is the number of shortest grid walks form G to J which:

a) go through H but not E

b) go through neither E nor F nor H

I can't seem to get the right logic for these..

Comment: Hint: let $f(x,y)$ be the number of shortest walks from $(0,0)$ to $J$ then $f(0,0)=1$, $f(x,y)=f(x-1,y)+f(x,y-1)$ as one walks to $(x,y)$ only from either $(x-1,y)$ or $(x,y-1)$. So you just manually sum $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

For a), you can find $[p(G,H)-p(G,E)p(E,H)]\cdot p(H,J)$

$\hspace{.4 in}$where  $p(A,B)$ is the number of paths from A to B.

For b), let $e$ be the set of paths from G to J going through E, and similarly for $f$ and $h$.

$\hspace{.4 in}$If S is the set of all paths from G to J, then

$\hspace{.4 in}|e^c\cap f^c\cap h^c|=|S|-|e|-|f|-|h|+|e\cap f|+|e\cap h|+|f\cap h|-|e\cap f\cap h|$.

Comment: Since $f$ and $h$ are disjoint, we also see  $|f\cap h|=0$ and $|e\cap f \cap h|=0$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks -- that's a good observation.  (I realized that the last term was 0, but didn't think about $|f\cap h|$.)

Comment: You're welcome. In fact due to the *shortest* path walks from $A=(x_A,y_A)$ to $B=(x_B,y_B)$ we could define a partial ordering $A\preceq B$ iff $x_A\leq x_B$ and $y_A\leq y_B$. Whenever two points are *not comparable* the corresponding set of pathes from $A$ to $B$ is empty.